# Convert [HH:MM AM/PM] String to ISO Date in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, date-comparison, isodate

I have two string values which contains Start Time and End Time. They are in following format:

```
StartTime 07:00 AM
EndTime   10:00 PM
```

I need to check whether Current Date Time is within these Start and End times.
Therefore, I need to convert above two strings to ISO datetime.

What is the best way to convert `[HH:MM AM/PM]` string in to ISO date time in Mongo DB?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/

Comment: MongoDB does not support 12-hour clock natively. You need you use a 3rd party library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [day.js](https://day.js.org/en/) or write your own custom function.